# C++ - How to get strings from a file to be saved as separate strings

Tags: c++, file, delimiter, getline

Any help on this would be appreciated as I am very stuck.

For this project, we have to first get the input from a file. 
Here was what the file could look like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Hi     Then  Finish
       End   Okay

----------------------------------------------------------------

Here is the layout for it:
Character Set 1: 1-6
Character Set 2: 7 (always a space)
Character Set 3: 8-11 
Character Set 4: 12-13 (always 2 spaces)
Character Set 5: 14-19
```

I was wondering if there is a way to getline a certain number of characters for a string. Also each of the character sets would have different variables.

For example: Character Set 1 would be called **label**, Character Set 3 would be **code**, and character set 5 would be **operation**.

I tried something like

```
for (int i = 0; !text.eof(); i++){
   getline(text, label[i]);
   getline(text, code[i]);
   getline(text, operation[i]);
}
```

If it helps any, here is my code at the moment... even though it isn't working properly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  const int MAX     = 100;
  string    str;
  string    symLabel[MAX];
  string    opCode  [MAX];
  string    operand [MAX];

  ifstream sim("simprog.txt");

  for (int i = 0; !sim.eof(); i++){

    getline(sim, str);

    symLabel[i] = str.substr(0, 6);
    opCode[i]   = str.substr(8,11);
    operand[i]  = str.substr(13, 18);

    cout << symLabel[i] << endl;
    cout << opCode[i]   << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example what would be the label for the second line? Would it be null?

Comment: Yes. I believe it would just be null. 

It is supposed to be like a set of instructions. 
Like, if I had a 3rd line and the label variable had something, I want the code to read it like: 
Line 1 has an instruction. Line 2 is blank. Line 3 has an instruction. It would still say that the label is on the third instruction.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Also, is the layout of the file fixed? Will the field always be of a predetermined width like you described?

Comment: Yes. It will always be 6 characters for the first column, a space, 4 characters for the second column, 2 spaces, and 6 characters for the last column. The first column will sometimes only have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your arrays to a vector of rec where rec is a structure of your strings with copy constructor and operator= added to make it compatible with STL containers. This will not limit you to a specific number of input lines. The rest is just some changes to your code.

```
struct rec
{
    rec() { }
    rec(const rec &r) { *this = r; }
    rec &operator=(const rec &r)
    {
        if (this != &r)
        {
            symLabel = r.symLabel;
            opCode = r.opCode;
            operand = r.operand;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    std::string    symLabel;
    std::string    opCode;
    std::string    operand;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::string    str;
   std::vector<rec> records;

   std::ifstream sim("simprog.txt");

   char bf[100];
   while(sim.good())
   {
       sim.getline(bf, sizeof(bf));
       str = bf;

       rec r;
       r.symLabel = str.substr(0, 6);
       r.opCode   = str.substr(7, 5);
       r.operand  = str.substr(13, 6);

       records.push_back(r);
   }

   for (size_t i=0; i< records.size(); i++)
   {
       std::cout << records[i].symLabel << std::endl;
       std::cout << records[i].opCode   << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Please note that this requires a properly formatted file as you specified it. If line format changes, or last line is incomplete you'll get into trouble :)